# Splitting a file using java

Tags: java, file, split

I have a 4Gb file.

```
path = "D:\Try\FourGBFile.txt"
```

Say,

```
File file = new File(path);
```

I wanna split the contents of this file into 4 files. How would i do it?

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180078/split-file-java-linux

Comment: @Jason: The link tagged as Java but its answer is linux script not Java.

Comment: @MM. See under best answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11180527/1260702

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the length of the file:

   ```
   long len = file.length();
   ```
2. Open a `FileInputStream` to your source file
3. Open as many `FileOutputStream` as you want/need
4. Write each part of the file by reading from the input stream and writing to the respective output stream, using the length of the file